# MySQL Join AND EXISTS in combination

Tags: mysql, join, exists

**Case**
I got the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_parking`
JOIN `parking_address` ON `parking_parking`.`parking_address` = `parking_address`.`address_id`
WHERE `parking_id` = 3
```

This query selects information about a parking (address and data about the parking itself)

And in general.. IT WORKS!

**Problem**

There is a small problem though..
Whenever the address has been deleted from the database and the parking itself still exists. The entire query returns 0. Simply because it looks for and **A** AND **B** as linked. But if one not found the second won't be returned either.

Now there is a solution..
**EXISTS**

However I do not know how to use it.

I tried:

```
EXISTS JOIN 

JOIN EXISTS 

JOIN `parking_address` ON EXISTS
```

But to no avail.

I hope (and guess) I have overlooked a small thing.

> **Note**
>
> !! I do not use this in real life! !!
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM
> ```
>
> *I did this one when I was still at the veeeery basics and I found out the hard way that even the simplest pages took ages to load.*

**Solution by : *GolezTrol***

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_parking`
LEFT JOIN `parking_address` ON `parking_parking`.`parking_address` = `parking_address`.`address_id`
WHERE `parking_id` = 3
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `join` (which is short for `inner join`) to `left join` (= `left outer join`). This will return all *parkings* and will just return `null` for the address fields if there is no matching *address*:

```
SELECT * FROM `parking_parking`
LEFT JOIN `parking_address` 
  ON `parking_parking`.`parking_address` = `parking_address`.`address_id`
WHERE `parking_id` = 3
```